# Piping to PowerShell from CMD

Tags: powershell

TLDR: Why can I not pipe streamed output between two POWERSHELL.exe instances?

I want to tail an `input.txt` file and pipe it's content to *any* CLI which accepts STDIN. The consumer may be PowerShell.exe, php.exe, awk, python, sed etc.

My assumption is that STDIN and STDOUT are universal concepts which all CLIs speak and thus I should be able to pipe from CMD/DOS commands to/from POWERSHELL.exe happily.

**input.txt:**

```
hello
world
```

My desired mode of operation is that, as lines are added to `input.txt` they are piped immediately to a CLI which accepts STDIN. From within PowerShell this can be simulated as:

```
Get-Content -Wait input.txt | ForEach-Object {$_}
```

It works as I desire apart from extra newlines which are of no concern here:

```
hello
world

I'm adding lines and saving and...

...they appear here...

yaaaay
```

Now, I encapsulate this tail functionalty as `tail.ps1` and then make a simple consumer script `process.ps1` which I will chain together:

**tail.ps1:**

```bsh
Get-Content -Watch .\input.txt
```

**process.ps1:**

```bsh
process {
   $_
}
```

I am explicitly using the `process{}` block because I want streamed piping and not some `end{}` block loop.

Again, this works from within the PowerShell Shell:

```
PS> .\tail.ps1 | .\process.ps1
hello
world

here is a new line saved to input.txt
```

Now I want to consider each of these scripts as a separate CLI which can be called from CMD / DOS:

```
C:\>POWERSHELL -f tail.ps1 | POWERShell -f process.ps1
```

This does not work - no output is produced and my question is WHY NOT??

Also just piping some input TO powershell.exe `process.ps1` produces no output:

```
C:\>type input.txt | POWERSHELL -f process.ps1
```

However, piping FROM PowerShell to, say, AWK does work:

```
C:\>POWERSHELL -f tail.ps1 | awk /e/
Hello
here is a newline with an e
so we're good
```

Why is AWK accepting the piped lines but `POWERShell process.ps1` not?

Another puzzling example run from CMD/DOS:

```
C:\>powershell -c "'hello';'world'"
hello
world       << This is as it should be
C:\>powershell -c "'hello';'world'"  | powershell -f process.ps1
            << No output appears - why not!?
W:\other>powershell -c "'hello';'world'"  | powershell -c "$input"
hello
world       << Powershell does get the stdin
```

Comment: `$_` != `$input`

Comment: Indeed, `$input` is the entire piped input object and `$_` is the individual item in the collection being processed.

Comment: `$_` is the current object in a (PowerShell) pipeline. However, a CMD pipeline is not a PowerShell pipeline and does not automagically populate `$_`. You need `$input` to enumerate the input to the script for that to happen. Please check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables).

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround which gets things streaming nicely though I do not yet have an explanation:

**process.ps1**:

```bsh
begin {if($input){}}
process {
    $_
}
```

It seems, without a `begin{}` block which accesses `$input` no `process{}` block is entered.

This may well be a PowerShell bug since it functions correctly within powershell.

Comment: `process { $input }` will suffice.

Comment: `$input` enumerates the script input. That is AFAICS what gets `$_` populated in your code snippet. See also my other comment to your question.